# Big-O in a database with UDF

Tags: database, algorithm, db2, time-complexity, big-o

I want to use a UDF to link tables in a database.  I'm not sure the impact on the speed of my query.

From what I read, queries have Big-O notation of, at max, log(n).  This is for doing a tree search.  If I added 14 lines of code for each check, I'm thinking this would still keep the algorithm at log(n).  Is that correct?

I must confess I haven't used a UDF in a query.  Could you use the UDF in the ON clause?  Or, would you use it in the WHERE clause?  What would be the impact on speed for each choice?

Here's the function I'm thinking (written in Excel VBA and not Db2.)

```
Function ismymatch(needle As String, haystack As String)

num_to_match = 10

If Len(needle) < num_to_match Then
ismymatch = False
Exit Function
End If

For i = 1 To Len(needle) - num_to_match + 1

    If InStr(haystack, Mid(needle, i, num_to_match)) > 0 Then
        ismymatch = True
        Exit Function

    End If




Next

ismymatch = False



End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are oversimplifying the problem. Queries in general do not have complexity of "at max, log(n)". A binary tree search algorithm does, but there are many more other things happening when a query is executed, and the execution plan may not even include a binary tree search. The latter will likely be the case if a user-defined function is used in a predicate.

Create a function, write a query, and look at its execution plan -- this is the only reliable way to evaluate its complexity and the function's impact on the query performance.